# Bash Echo Escape Sequences

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, centos

I'm trying to write a bash script in CentOS that tests the various echo escape sequences. However, when I run the program

> ./test.sh a

I keep getting this error message:

> bad interpretation: no such file or directory

Here is the script:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Test echo escape sequences

input=$1

case $input in
   a ) echo -e "\a" testing \a;;
   b ) echo -e "\b" testing \b;;
   c ) echo -e "\c" testing \c;;
   * ) echo Incorrect input
   exit 1;;
esac
```

Where did I go wrong?

EDIT: I'm running CentOS Minimal guest in VirtualBox on a Windows XP host

EDIT 2:

```
 #! bin/bash
```

was in my script, not

```
#! /bin/bash
```

When I changed it to

```
 #! /bin/bash
```

and run the program ./test.sh a, it just prints "a"

Comment: @AdrianCornish: I suspect that it cannot find `bash`, either because it's not installed (not very likely), not installed in `bin` (again not very likely) or it's saved with Windows line endings so it cannot find `/bin/bash^M` (I had this problem before).

Comment: My version of bash gives the error bash: ./test.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory if line endings are a problem

Comment: What do you get when you run `file ./test.sh`?

Comment: +1 @Eugen and AdrianCornish You were right, I had #! bin/bash not #! /bin/bash. The program runs now, but all it does is print my character, for example it just prints "a"

Comment: This is because of the escape code IHMO

Comment: How do I get the computer to beep using "a", instead of displaying "a"?

Comment: \g was always the bell character ;-) (omg why do I remember that!)

Comment: I tried \g but all it does it display "g". Does it have anything to do with the fact i'm using VirtualBox? Also I got the \a from [Learning the Bash Shell 3rd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009656.do)

Comment: Well \g used to sound the pizo electric speaker in IBM type machines. In a VM with a fake sound card - who knows ;-) - something visual might be \n so you can see the newlines

Comment: Alternatively you could try colour by echoing something like '\e[1;32m'

Comment: '\e[1;32m' Nice, thanks, it worked @Adrian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EDIT] Based on the original post, this is usually caused by DOS LINE ENDINGS.

The CR in the CR/LF DOS line ending is being seen by the interpreter as part of the shell that should be used to execute the script.

So, it tries to load /bin/bash(CR) which does not exist, hence "bad interpreter" is displayed.

One easy way to correct this is to copy the contents of the script to the clipboard and then:

cat > test.sh
(PASTE CLIPBOARD)
(PRESS ENTER)
(PRESS CTRL-D)

This will strip out any incorrect line endings (there are other ways to do it but this is a pretty easy / straight-forward solution.

---

Once the "bad interpreter" issue was resolved, another syntax error in the script is the use of "\a" when you probably intend '\a'.

---

[EDIT] I think I realize what you mean now.  Try this instead:

echo -e '\a' testing '\\'a

Comment: Just FYI I did in fact confirm this by creating a file with DOS line endings, trying to run in MacOS X gives a similar (but slightly different) error than displayed in the original post.

Comment: I actually had #! bin/bash in my script, not #! /bin/bash

Comment: I updated my answer based on your feedback.  Why is the script in the post different from the one on your system?  Are there possibly any other discrepancies?

Answer (score 2):

Did you make the script executable with something like

```
   chmod 755 test.sh
```

**Added**

I wonder if part of the problem is the escape sequence you are using as they could mean \a=cursor up \b=cursor down \c=cursor forward.

Or also interpreted as \a=SOH Start of Heading \b=STX Start of Text or \c=ETX End of Text

Comment: Your script works for me. What escape sequences are you expecting?